# email template position absolute?

Tags: html-email

Is it safe to use `position:absolute` in a email template?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depends on which mail clients your users are using. Outlook for example handles position: absolute well, Thunderbird on the other hand doesn't.

I would try designing your mail-template as "normal" as possible. Tables help a lot for example (yuck).

See the following page about styling tips on HTML mails, including some position absolute advice:

- [Style In Email](https://web.archive.org/web/20161126040749/http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Style_In_Email)

Comment: **Update:** Outlook 2007 and up doesn't support `position:absolute`, and at least some versions of Gmail, Yahoo Mail, and possibly Hotmail don't support it either.

Comment: The Style in Email link is broken!

Comment: Replaced the link with an archive.org link

Answer (score 12):

Adding to an old question, I know - but I can confirm that neither GMail supports position: absolute at the moment.

Comment: what should I use instead of `position:absolute`? I tried to give negative margin but failed.

Comment: gmail is no longer supported

Answer (score 9):

it is not a safe manner to use position absolute in emailers,because all of the email server did'nt support the tag..instead using postion absolute you guys can use

```html
<table width="100%" align="center" style="Margin:0px; Padding:0px; border-collapse:collapse; background-color:rgb(255,255,255);max-width:600px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" background="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/BGGdOwY.jpg">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top">
              <p Style="Margin-top:45px; text-align:left; line-height: 24px; letter-spacing: 0.55px; Margin-bottom:10px; font-family:'Open Sans',arial,sans-serif!important; width: 540px;">Dear Artist/Vendor,</p>
              <p Style="text-align:justify; line-height: 24px; letter-spacing: 0.55px; Margin-top:10px; Margin-bottom:10px; font-family:'Open Sans',arial,sans-serif!important; width: 540px;">We've received a request to reset your password. If you didn't make the request, just ignore this email. Otherwise, you can reset your password using this link:</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

even you guys can use clickable button on it by adding this code in another td

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" >
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="Margin:0px; Padding:0px;">
    <table width="100%" align="center" style="Margin:0px; Padding:0px; border-collapse:collapse; background-color:rgb(255,255,255);" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <table width="100%" align="center" style="Margin:0px; Padding:0px; border-collapse:collapse; background-color:rgb(255,255,255);max-width:600px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" background="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/BGGdOwY.jpg">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <table width="100%" align="center" style="Margin:0px auto; Padding:0px; border-collapse:n-left: 20px; max-width:600px; " border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                    <p Style="Margin-top:45px; text-align:left; line-height: 24px; letter-spacing: 0.55px; Margin-bottom:10px; font-family:'Open Sans',arial,sans-serif!important; width: 540px;">Dear Artist/Vendor,</p>
                                                    <p  Style="text-align:justify; line-height: 24px; letter-spacing: 0.55px; Margin-top:10px; Margin-bottom:10px; font-family:'Open Sans',arial,sans-serif!important; width: 540px;">We've received a request to reset your password. If you didn't make the request, just ignore this email. Otherwise, you can reset your password using this link:</p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <table width="100%" align="left" style="Margin:0px auto; Padding:0px; border-collapse:collapse;  max-width:600px; Margin-left: 20px;  Margin-top:15px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                    <a href="https://www.google.co.in/" style="padding: 10px 35px; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; background-color:#000000; letter-spacing: 0.55px; text-align:left; line-height: 24px; font-family:'Open Sans',arial,sans-serif!important;">Reset Your Password</a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    
                    
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: The `background` attribute is not supported by Outlook. To overcome this issue, you could use VML. Check [this](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6173-fixed-outlook-background-images) post for example.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Style in Email](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Style_In_Email), neither `AOL` (before release 9) nor `Mozilla Mail`/`ThunderBird` (all versions) support absolute positioning in the email body.

Comment: The Style in Email link is broken!

Answer (score 0):

**absolute in css** not working for HTML email. 
If you gonna use absolute for *Image combination*, you can use such style.

```
 background-image: url(url_to_your_image);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Outlook doesn't have direct support for background-image.